Is 2'6" within the size constraints of small, and what would the weight of a fairy that size be?
Our first session is on September 4th, so I need to figure out the minor details of my character.
My thought process is, if 5' is medium, and enlarge/reduce makes you half your size and you count as one size smaller, then 2'6" would be within small.
As for the second one, google was not helpful at all with that, so I made a guess of 20 lbs for a 14 year old 2'6" fairy. Is that weight accurate?

Just to clarify, for your dimensions above, you're talking about the Height of the creature right?

@Mathaddict yes, the height and weight of a fairy pc

Generally the square-cube law can be used
5e generally follows the square-cube law for size changes. Thus, if your size halves then your height halves and your weight decreases by a factor of 8.
This is most evident with the Enlarge/Reduce spell, which says:

The target’s size is halved in all dimensions, and its weight is reduced to one-eighth of normal. This reduction decreases its size by one category—from Medium to Small, for example.

With regards to your example, a 5' person reasonably could weigh 160 pounds. Thus, if they are reduced, they will then be 2.5' tall and weigh 20 pounds.
So yes, your weight estimate is accurate.

Ok, thanks for the help with my character's size. I just wanted to make sure.

@Tasi I would also consider their build and how they are proportioned, though - as well as Str and Dex scores if you like.  Do they look more like this, or this?  Take the height and weight they would have if they were human-sized and then scale using the square-cube law.

You might also refer to statistics of real live humans that are 2'6". As they are children, you might want to fudge the numbers a bit.

For the record, square-cube performs pretty poorly approximating bipeds (increases and decreases in height don't apply proportionately to other dimensions). A 5' tall person would be ridiculously buff, moderately obese, or incredibly stocky (dwarf build?) at 160 pounds. A 2'6" person (who wasn't a growing child, where the reasonable ranges are much wider, cause growth is a weird and uneven process) would be dangerously underweight at 20 lbs.

@Kirt I was thinking tulin. Like, from Legend of Zelda Tears of the Kingdom.

@ShadowRanger my answer is strictly a rules as written approach. I'm avoiding the biology limits so as to avoid an answer that tries to use 5e as a physics simulator.

The new races don't really have height/weight listings, but tell you to go look at the PH and see which entry fits for you.
Halflings, being the standard "small" race, have a height of 2'7" +2d4 inches, giving a range of heights from 2'9" to 3'3" and weight range from 37 lbs to 43 lbs (35 + 1 lb per inch rolled)
Going by that, 2'6" is a long way into Small territory (maybe even verging on Tiny, honestly), but 20 lbs is probably undershooting by a long way. If you want to extrapolate from the Halfling minimums, 2'6" and 30 lbs is probably a better set of numbers and that's still going to be in "waifishly thin" territory (which is appropriate for fairy, in my opinion).

For a non serious addition to the weight conversation, halflings famously eat more meals than the average fantasy race: "We've had one, yes. But what about second breakfast?"
